# PHP Return 400 With error message

Tags: php, rest

I'm creating a PHP REST backend, and reactjs front end. And as per most codes that I've seen, I'm trying to follow the try and catch method when doing CRUD.

```
try {
something
} catch {
error
}
```

Where the the error is caught when my rest api is returning a http error code 400 by calling the following in PHP.

```
http_response_code(400)
```

For example if a user try to login with USERNAME and PaSSWORD, but it doesn't match, I suppose I will need to throw a 400 error? However, how do I send a message with the reason for the 400 error e.g. Password and Username do not match.

I tried to do the following but the browser only caught 400 (Bad Request). I cannot see the error message.

```
http_response_code(400);
echo "Username and Password do not match";
die();
```

or was I doing it right when for all these years I was doing this.

```
try {

 Ajax call to http://www.example.com/api
 if ($response['error'] === 'true') {
    if ($response['code'] == '400') {
        //display $response['message']
    }
 }
```

then on the backend i just do

```
$response['error'] = true;
$response['message'] = 'Username and Password do not match';

echo json_encode($response);
die();
```

Any difference when I am creating a REST API, and giving error via different methods above?

Comment: 400 is not the right code to signal authentication failure, there are better ones, check the list of HTTP status codes. Further, anything you `echo` does not become part of the response status line but part of the body. That said, I don't really understand what your question is, HTTP puts very few restrictions on how you use error codes, you can use them as you like. Similarly, how you handle them on the client side is pretty much up to you.

Comment: my meaning is, should I be using http codes for these kind of errors?

Comment: That's a matter of taste. The way I'd go is to use existing HTTP authentication mechanisms, but for the parameters of call and the response I'd use the body. That is *not* the REST way though.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I manage to figure out I can get the "echo" from the xhr body and make the correct error message displayed.